# Searching a Numpy Array for the index of a subarray based on a subarray of the subarray

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

I want to get the index of a 2d array which contains a specific array. In this case I want to know where in the array `array` the array `[[4, 5], 6]` is but only based on the inner most array `[4, 5]` so that I get its position even if instead of the six it would be an eight.

This is my code so far:

```
import numpy as np

array = np.array([[[1, 2], 3], [[4, 5], 6], [[7, 8], 9]])

print(np.where(array == [4, 5]))
```

but as an output I get:

```
(array([], dtype=int32), array([], dtype=int32))
```

and the output I want is the following:

```
(array([1], dtype=int32), array([0], dtype=int32))
```

Comment: `where` is only as good as the boolean argument.  What is `array== [4,5]`?  For that matter look at (and print) `array`.  Make sure you know exactly what that is.  Have you tried to do this with lists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are working with a dtype object where your first numpy column contains list objects.

You can create a `vectorized function` to check each object individually.

```
f = np.vectorize(lambda x: x==[4,5])
idx = np.where(f(array))
idx
```

```
(array([1]), array([0]))
```

---

You can also use a `list comprehension` after flattening out the array and then checking each object against `[4,5]`. Then you could use `np.where` or just plain simple boolean check to get the index in that flat list, which you could `unravel_index` to get the position in the 2D `array`. (I am using `np.where` because you want to use it)

```
check = [i==[4,5] for i in array.ravel()]
np.unravel_index(*np.where(check), array.shape)
```

```
(array([1]), array([0]))
```

Comment: Vectorize here will actually be very slow, it's just a convenience wrapper around a loop.

Comment: you are absolutely correct, which is why I provided another method. In any case, python is not the right language for performance, but only readability. The first method is very readable.

Comment: @user3483203, since this an object dtype array, most operations occur at list comprehension speeds.  `vectorize` isn't much slower.  `frompyfunc` is even closer to the list speeds.